# TabBarView with variable height inside a ListView

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView with multiple type of items, one of which is a widget of TabBar and TabBarView.
The problem is each tab page's height is different and I want the ListView to wrap the tab widget dynamically according to it's height
[image: Like this]
But the TabBarView doesn't accept unbounded height and ListView can't provide a height for it's children.
Is there anyway this can be done? Or must I use the TabBar with something that can wrap it's content like a Column and sacrifice the ability to swipe between tabs?

Comment: I do not think this is possible with TabBarView. It is made to be used asa view, not as an inline content. Making your own should be easy though

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need to have TabView to show Tabs content.
the minus of this approcach that you are loosing animations and swipes, so you will need to do it by your self if you realy will need it.

[image]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Widget> myTabs = [
    Tab(text: 'one'),
    Tab(text: 'two'),
    Tab(text: 'three'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    super.initState();
  }

  _handleTabSelection() {
    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  _listItem() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 1,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
      ),
      height: 120,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('List Item', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _listItem(),
          TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            labelColor: Colors.redAccent,
            tabs: myTabs,
          ),
          Center(
            child: [
              Text('first tab'),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text('second tab'),
                  ...List.generate(10, (index) => Text('line: $index'))
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text('third tab'),
                  ...List.generate(20, (index) => Text('line: $index'))
                ],
              ),
            ][_tabController.index],
          ),
          _listItem(),
          _listItem(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you know why I get "The argument type '_RentScreenState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'" with vsync: this?

Comment: @Dani you have to `add with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`  to the end of your State’s class declaration.

Comment: tbh I don't remember. Only thing I know now is that it works well :D

Answer (score 29):

Don't use `TabBarView`, use `IndexedStack` with `Visibility` instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: selectedIndex,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 128,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 256,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            TabBar(
              tabs: <Tab>[
                Tab(text: 'Tab Left'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab Right'),
              ],
              controller: tabController,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                  tabController.animateTo(index);
                });
              },
            ),
            Divider(height: 0),
            IndexedStack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Visibility(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Content left'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  maintainState: true,
                  visible: selectedIndex == 0,
                ),
                Visibility(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Content right'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  maintainState: true,
                  visible: selectedIndex == 1,
                ),
              ],
              index: selectedIndex,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`IndexedStack` will show a single child from a list of children based on `index` while `Visibility` will maintain to show or hide view. When the view is hiding, so there is no excess white space to show (stack height is equal to the maximum height of its children).

Here is the dartpad https://dartpad.dev/535f06aa01257b049c7f2f9c719c9881.

Comment: Do dot forget
```tabController.dispose();```

Comment: Yes, override it at dispose method. Thanks

Comment: That's an awesome solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome. Though is it possible to make them scrollable?

Comment: Of course, you can change the child container using listview or singlechildscrollview with column

Comment: Perfect solution, but this can be improved. There is no need to wrap the children with Visibility, the IndexStack will only display one child at a time given by its index property.

Comment: Yes, but all of children will have the same height. Visibility will do the trick to hide not visible child. But you can remove it if you don't mind having same height to all children.

Comment: you lose the horizontal scroll with this

Comment: Yea, you're right. I use a lot this workaround when having multiple widget of list, grid and tab on a single page.

Comment: No animation???

Comment: how to add swipe functionality similar to the tabs? is it possible

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          DummySection(height: 100.0,color: Colors.red,),
          DummySection(height: 150.0,color: Colors.yellow,),
          Container(
            height: 350.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TabBar(
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue[100],
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.lightBlue
                  ),
                  controller: tabController,
                  tabs: <Widget>[
                    Tab(text: "Home",),
                    Tab(text: "Fav",),
                    Tab(text: "Star",)
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: tabController,
                      children: [
                        DummyList(),
                        DummyList(),
                        DummyList()
                      ]
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          DummySection(height: 100.0,color: Colors.red,),
          DummySection(height: 100.0,color: Colors.pink,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Dummy List Container
class DummySection extends StatelessWidget{
  Color color;
  double height;
  DummySection({this.color,this.height});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      color: color,
      height: height,
    );
  }
}
// Dummy Listing for tab
class DummyList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: Container(
              height: 200.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("hello"),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: Container(
              height: 200.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("hello"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @pierre Used `ListView` widget & inside that add `DummySection ` widget which one have `Container` with some height.( You can also add container directly in listview.)

For TabarView i added `Container` widget with some heigh. Inside that used column for `Tab & TabBarView`.

Comment: My intention is for the TabBarView to change it's height based on it's current child content. With your code, the TabBarView will have a fixed-height of (350 - TabBar height) and will be overflowed if it's child's height is larger than that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it to somewhat imitate tabs animation transition, using the `AnimatedSwitcher` widget (with 3 tabs):

```
 TabController _tabController;
 ValueNotifier<int> _currentScreen = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
 int _previousScreen = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _currentScreen.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }      

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CustomScrollBar.Scrollbar(
          child: ListView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
    
              /// Tabbar
              TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                indicatorColor: ColorData.accentColor,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21),
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                onTap: (i) {
                  _previousScreen = _currentScreen.value;
                  _currentScreen.value = i;
                },
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Text('Screen 1'),
                  Text('Screen 2'),
                  Text('Screen 3'),
                ],
              ),
    
              /// Tab View
              ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
                  valueListenable: _currentScreen,
                  builder: (context, screen, child) {
                    return AnimatedSwitcher(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      switchInCurve: Curves.easeOut,
                      switchOutCurve: Curves.easeIn,
                      transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                        final inAnimation =
                            Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0)).animate(animation);
                        final outAnimation =
                            Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(-1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0)).animate(animation);
    
                        final Widget inTransition = ClipRect(
                          child: SlideTransition(
                            position: inAnimation,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: child,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
    
                        final Widget outTransition = ClipRect(
                          child: SlideTransition(
                            position: outAnimation,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: child,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
    
                        //// Transition for two screens
    //                    if (child.key == ValueKey<int>(1)) {
    //                      print(_previousScreen);
    ////                    if (_previousScreen < screen) {
    //                      return ClipRect(
    //                        child: SlideTransition(
    //                          position: inAnimation,
    //                          child: Padding(
    //                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    //                            child: child,
    //                          ),
    //                        ),
    //                      );
    //                    } else {
    //                      return ClipRect(
    //                        child: SlideTransition(
    //                          position: outAnimation,
    //                          child: Padding(
    //                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    //                            child: child,
    //                          ),
    //                        ),
    //                      );
    //                    }

                        //// Transition for three screens
                        if (child.key == ValueKey<int>(1)) {
                          if (_previousScreen == 0 || _previousScreen == 1 && screen != 2) return inTransition;
                          return outTransition;
                        } else if (child.key == ValueKey<int>(2)) {
                          return inTransition;
                        } else {
                          return outTransition;
                        }
                      },
                      child: _returnTab(screen),
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      _returnTab(int screen) {
        switch (screen) {
          case 0:
            return ScreenOne(
              key: ValueKey<int>(0),
            );
            break;
          case 1:
            return ScreenTwo(
              key: ValueKey<int>(1),
            );
            break;
          case 2:
            return ScreenThree(
              key: ValueKey<int>(2),
            );
            break;
        }
```

Looks nice for me :)