# Flutter - Change the animation of TabBarView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I implemented a basic TabBar and TabBarView with a DefaultTabController, see code below.

```
class MyApp2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: BOTTOM_TABS,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom App Bar')),
        body: _tabBarView(),
        bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTabBar(),
      ),
    );
  }

  _tabBarView() {
    return TabBarView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.lightGreen,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _bottomTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      tabs: [
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.public),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.group),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.person),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Works great! Now what I want to do is change the animation between the two tabs from the default animation. But I can't find an easy way to do that.

After a bit of research it seems like I need to use a custom TabController and somehow use its [animateTo](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController/animateTo.html) method. To me that seems like a pretty big change just to change the animation.  **What I wonder is if that is the correct way or if I am missing some easier way to just change the default animation between the tabviews?**

If someone could give me some good resources to point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not hard, just use TabController (to do so you need to use SingleTickerProviderStateMixin ) and AnimatedBuilder.

[image]

```
class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyApp2State createState() => _MyApp2State();
}

class _MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  _tabBarView() {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _tabController.animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: _tabController.animation.value * pi,
          child: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ][_tabController.animation.value.round()],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _bottomTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      labelColor: Colors.black,
      tabs: [
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.public),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.group),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.person),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom App Bar')),
        body: _tabBarView(),
        bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTabBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does that double array mean in Transform.rotate() inside _tabBarView function ? Is that like a multidimensional array ?

Comment: it's not double array. In the first brackets is the list of tabs, and in the second brackets is the index of the current tab.

Comment: if you wanted to have no animation at all, would this approach be useful too?

Comment: then you don't need tabview, just add all tabs widgets in a list, and save tabController.index in state. to do that you need addListener to tabController, and save index when indexIsChanging, similar idea is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547731/tabbarview-with-variable-height-inside-a-listview, but you don't need indexed stack...

Comment: this is one of a few working examples one the web, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Screenshot (Null safe):**

[image]

---

**Code:**

If you want fine-grained control, you can make use of the `AnimationController`.

```dart
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController;
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      value: 1,
    );

    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    )..addListener(() {
        if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
          setState(() => _controller.forward(from: 0.5));
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ScaleTransition(
        scale: _controller,
        child: [
          Container(color: Colors.red),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ][_tabController.index],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        tabs: [
          Tab(child: Text('Red')),
          Tab(child: Text('Green')),
          Tab(child: Text('Blue')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable animation between flutter tabs by setting animation duration to zero like this

```
    tabController = TabController(
    animationDuration: Duration.zero,
    length: 4, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
```

Thank me later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to completely change the animation.

But if you just need some customization, did you try to use a `TabController` instead of a `DefaultTabController` ? 
You just need to pass the `tabController` as an arg to the `TabBar` & `TabBarView`.

To customize the animation with the `tabController`, you should specify an Animation for the `tabController` and also specify the curve and duration with the `animateTo` function of the `tabController`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController/animateTo.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html