# Is it possible to animate the transition between the tabs of a CupertinoTabScaffold?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I'm using the sample below (taken from the [CupertinoTabScaffold documentation page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabScaffold-class.html)).

There is a "slide" transition when pushing a new route inside the tab, but when I click on a tabbar item, the content is brutally replaced. How can I have a transition when switching between tabs?

I would like implement something like that: https://github.com/Interactive-Studio/TransitionableTab

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
  tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
        title: Text("Tab 0"),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.news),
        title: Text("Tab 1"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return CupertinoTabView(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoPageScaffold(
          navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text('Page 1 of tab $index'),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: CupertinoButton(
              child: const Text('Next page'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                          middle: Text('Page 2 of tab $index'),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: CupertinoButton(
                            child: const Text('Back'),
                            onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop(); },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: I've just saw this question, did you find a solution? otherwise , do you need to use `CupertinoTabScaffold` , did you try using a custom widget?

Comment: use animateTo(index)

Comment: At the link that you shared, there are 4 main transitions: Move, Scale, Fade, and Custom which one you need?

Answer (score 1):

May be this package will be help you `page_transition: ^2.0.5`
[https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition](https://Page%20Transition)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
It has info on how to animate tabBarView but should be similar to CupertinoTabView

```
class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _MyApp2State createState() => _MyApp2State();
}

class _MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  _tabBarView() {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _tabController.animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: _tabController.animation.value * pi,
          child: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ][_tabController.animation.value.round()],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _bottomTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      labelColor: Colors.black,
      tabs: [
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.public),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.group),
        ),
        Tab(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.person),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom App Bar')),
        body: _tabBarView(),
        bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTabBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code is taken from the following link-
[Flutter - Change the animation of TabBarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889604/flutter-change-the-animation-of-tabbarview)