# How can I place TabBarView Widget correctly in a Column Widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

There was an error placing TabBar and TabBarView in the Column Widget in the Scaffold.

My Source Code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CustomView(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomBox(),
            CustomTitle(),
            CustomMainText(),
            CustomButton(),
            CustomTabView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTabView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'tab1'),
              Tab(text: 'tab2'),
            ],
          ),
          TabBarView( // Here is Line 132.
            children: [
              Container(),
              Container(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TabBarView TabBarView:file:///C:/Users/rbqls/AndroidStudioProjects/myfirstflutterproject/lib/main.dart:132:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1424:15)
#1      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1436:6)
#2      RenderBox.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2329:12)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1831:9)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#19     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#23     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#24     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#25     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#27     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#28     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#29     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#31     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:504:14)
#32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#47     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#48     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#52     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#53     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1005:7)
#54     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#55     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#60     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#66     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#68     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#70     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#71     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#72     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#79     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3428:13)
#80     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#83     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:751:15)
#84     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#85     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#86     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#87     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#88     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#89     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#90     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#91     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#92     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#93     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#94     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#95     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#96     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#97     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#98     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#99     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#100    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#101    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1852:7)
#102    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#103    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1707:7)
#104    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:879:18)
#105    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:497:19)
#106    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#107    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#108    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1145:15)
#109    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#110    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#0158c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: right
...  crossAxisDirection: down
...  offset: _PagePosition#8e104(range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics -> PageScrollPhysics -> PageScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#1422c, ScrollDirection.idle)
...  anchor: 0.0
RenderObject: RenderViewport#0158c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: right
  crossAxisDirection: down
  offset: _PagePosition#8e104(range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics -> PageScrollPhysics -> PageScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#1422c, ScrollDirection.idle)
  anchor: 0.0
...  center child: _RenderSliverFractionalPadding#22595 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    geometry: null
...    child: RenderSliverFillViewport#65bf0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      geometry: null
...      no children current live
====================================================================================================
```

I was able to resolve the error with the fixed height value of TabBarView as shown in the code below:

```
...
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: TabBarView(
    children: [
      Container(),
      Container(),
    ],
  ),
),
...
```

However, because the size of the Container Widget in TabBarView changes dynamically, the height of the TabBarView must change dynamically to suit the size of the one of its children widget.

In addition, I have used various widgets such as Flexible, Expanded, and FittedBox, but I have not solved them.

Is there any other way than using a fixed height?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TabBarView with variable height inside a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547731/tabbarview-with-variable-height-inside-a-listview)

Comment: can you share your code with sizedBox which is breaking with dynamic height ??

Comment: @SalihCan Thank you. I decided to change the child widget using switch() without TabBarView. In addition, I wrapped this widget with a GuestDetector.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the content of TabBarView mannually instead using TabbarView itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try Expanded widget-

```
class CustomTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTabView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'tab1'),
              Tab(text: 'tab2'),
            ],
          ),
       Expanded(child:   TabBarView( // Here is Line 132.
            children: [
              Container(),
              Container(),
            ],
          ),
),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: This has not been working for me either